# Could not find matching constructor using Java

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to call a constructor in a groovy file. I've a constructor like

```
public class CreditCardDocumentImpl extends org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl implements creditcard.CreditCardDocument
{
    // Constructor
    public CreditCardDocumentImpl(org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType sType)
    {  
        super(sType);
    }
}
```

When I try to access the constructor by calling ,

```
// Call the constructor
CreditCardDocument creditCardDocument = new CreditCardDocumentImpl(SchemaType);
```

It doesn't allow me

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: creditcard.impl.CreditCardDocumentImpl(java.lang.Class)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an **instance** of SchemaType, not the **class** itself.

```
CreditCardDocument creditCardDocument = new CreditCardDocumentImpl(new SchemaType());
```

Comment: We cannot pass an instance like that. :(

Comment: The point is you have to pass an instance, or null. The groovy exception is saying you are passing a class object.

Comment: Can you help me what exactly I need to pass? I have tried to pass sType(null object of SchemaType), whereas SchemaType is an interface. Fighting with this since yesterday.

Comment: It depends on which schema you trying to use.if you have a XmlObject of this schema , you many try xmlObject.schemaType() to get the instance of the SchemaType. or XmlObject.type for anytype.

Comment: It is of org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType